# Unclear behaviour of \S

Tags: regex

Might be trivial, but I do not fully get why the following regex pattern:
"\Sa", when applied to the string " a aa", intercepts the first 'a' (in bold) as follows " a **aa**".

Comment: `\S` is **not whitespace** character, so `a` matches `\S`. `\Sa` pattern matches `aa` - *not whitespace* followed by `a`. Please, note, that `\Sa` doesn't match `" a"` since space is a whitespace

Comment: `\Sa` matches a non whitespace char follwed by `a`. That will match `aa` and not space a

Comment: See [**lower** `\s`](https://regex101.com/r/0bTXYX/1). The upper shorthands are usuallly the negation. same like `\d` for digit and `\D` for non digit or `\w` for word character and `\W` for non word character.